# docker adminer image cannot read login-ssl plugin from /var/www/html/plugins-enabled folder

Tags: php, docker

Hi I am trying to start the dockerized image of adminer but am not able to connect to a ssl enabled mysql database. When I try to provide the plugin name as described in the official docker documentation. When I run the command

```
docker run -e ADMINER_PLUGINS='login-ssl' adminer
```

I am still getting the same error. the rrror says 
Create a file "/var/www/html/plugins-enabled/login-ssl.php" with the following contents to load the plugin:

```
<?php
require_once('plugins/login-ssl.php');

/** 
    * @param array array("key" => filename, "cert" => filename, "ca" => filename)
    */
return new AdminerLoginSsl(
    $ssl = ???
);
```

I created the same file as described in the suggestion but still the same issue. Can someone please help me with setting the adminer.  Am I doing something wrong , please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the php files you don't need to specify the in the env `ADMINER_PLUGINS`

Here is my login-ssl.php

```
<?php
require_once('plugins/login-ssl.php');

$key = $_ENV['DB_SSL_KEY'];
$cert = $_ENV['DB_SSL_CERT'];
$ca = $_ENV['DB_SSL_CA'];

return new AdminerLoginSsl(
    $ssl = array("key" => $key, "cert" => $cert, "ca" => $ca)
);
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  adminer:
    image: adminer:4.7.7-standalone
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      ADMINER_DESIGN: nette
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: DB_IP_OR_HOST
      DB_SSL_KEY: '/certs/client-key.pem'
      DB_SSL_CERT: '/certs/client-cert.pem'
      DB_SSL_CA: '/certs/ca.pem'
    volumes:
      - ./login-ssl.php:/var/www/html/plugins-enabled/login-ssl.php
      - ./client-key.pem:/certs/client-key.pem
      - ./client-cert.pem:/certs/client-cert.pem
      - ./ca.pem:/certs/ca.pem
    restart: on-failure
```